# MySQL query return different rows after OPTIMIZE TABLE (from PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, innodb

I have this sample table on MySQL v.5.7.17 (InnoDB, 5.000 rows):

`+-------+----------+
| code1 | code2    |
+-------+----------+
|  4714 | 15895510 |
|  1041 | 10000158 |
|  2866 | 10000000 |
(...)`

Code 1 is indexed.
I test with a simple query: `SELECT code2 FROM codes WHERE code1=1041`
**Case 1:** I run it on MySQL console and return the correct value `10000158`.

**Case 2:** I run it from PHP (*mysqli_query()*) and no rows returned (*mysqli_num_rows()=0*).
If I run the same query but with a different code1 (`WHERE code1=2866`) I get a correct result: `10000000`.
I've been doing a lot of testing and never got the row for `code1=1041`.

Finally, I run a `OPTIMIZE TABLE codes` and I get the correct value from `code1=1041`! I'm surprised!

From the console has always worked. From PHP some records were not displayed. How can OPTIMIZE TABLE solve this problem in PHP? Could it be a corruption in the index and only affect PHP-Mysqli engine?

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that your underlying data is changing.

Comment: Could your php code to query the database be wrong?

Comment: When I have detected the problem I have created a script only to look for the error.
This script only had the basic code to make the connection (`mysqli_connect`) and the query (`mysqli_query`). And I test with (`mysqli_num_rows`).
At that moment no users modifing the table.

Comment: Don't use MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.

Comment: I use InnoDB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this is expected (or at least highly probable) behavior.  OPTIMIZE TABLE defragments the database *and* the indexes. If your indexes were corrupted (or even highly fragmented), this command will fix them.  My best guess is that your highly fragmented index was timing out during the search for that value and OPTIMIZE TABLE fixed that.

Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html
and also the accepted answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40769/will-optimize-table-have-any-impact-on-my-data)

Comment: I understand that may be what you say. But why did it work directly with the Mysql console and not with the PHP command? This is the strange thing!

Comment: Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969000/identical-mysql-query-returning-different-result-in-mysql-workbench-than-from-co) help?